# Will multiple Date() value(timestamp) be equal while initializing in same method and same thread?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm curious to know that initializing `Date()` objects in same method and same thread will be equal to orderedSame. I tried it with unit Test Case but It given various results as attached screenshots.

Test case failed at Assert#2:
[image]

Test case failed at Assert#4:
[image]

Test case Success:
[image]

I think, the time components of `Date()` will be changing based on the code execution time from `date1` to `date5`.

So can we say that the `Date()` object created at line #2 will be different from the one created in line #1?

Comment: Why should they be the same? Each Date() returns  the current time (modulo some resolution) when it is executed.

Comment: And why would you create separate object when you want the same value? Create one and use everywhere until you need a separate date.

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no reason to use `compare()` and `.orderedSame` with `Date` in Swift. `Date` conforms to `Equatable`. You can, and should, just use `==`. (I believe `NSDate` also correctly implements `==` in Swift, but there's no reason to use `NSDate` there IMO.)

Comment: @MartinR Even if array holds current date objects ex:[Date(), Date(), Date()], there is no guarantee that the date value in array are same. Right?

Comment: @Natarajan: If you do `let array = [Date(), Date(), Date()]` then three values are created successively, and these need not be equal. If you do `let array = Array(repeating: Date(), count: 3)` then only one value is created, and copied to all array elements.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @MartinR.

Comment: I don't mind downvote my question. If you could please provide the reason in comment, I can correct my mistakes in my question.

Comment: This question has four answers. I'm still wondering why the question is being downvoted even it has meaningful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assume anything. [`Date()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780470-init)

> Creates a date value initialized to the current date and time.

Two consecutive `Date()` calls can return the same value because

- the internal clock has a limited resolution,
- the date is stored as a `TimeInterval` aka `Double`, which has a limited
  precision.

Usually, the values would be non-decreasing, but even that need not be the case
because the user can change the time settings of the device.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `Date()` the system fetches the time from it's realtime clock. If any measurable time has passed between that call and the previous call, the dates will be different. `Date` objects use a `Double` count of seconds internally, which has a precision of ≈15 decimal digits, so they are able to measure tiny, tiny spans of time (less than a picosecond.) I don't know the precision of the realtime clock on iOS, but it's will likely be in nanoseconds.

Try running this code in release mode on your target device:

```
let arraySize = 1000
var array = [Date]()
var differences = 0
array.reserveCapacity(arraySize)
for _ in 1...arraySize {
    array.append(Date())
}
for index in 0 ..< arraySize-1 {
    if array[index] != array[index+1] {
        differences += 1
        let difference = array[index+1].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate -
            array[index].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        print("Dates at index \(index) are different! by \(difference)")
    }
}
if differences == 0 {
    print("All dates are equal")
} else {
    print("\(differences) dates were different out of \(arraySize)")
}
```

I ran it as a command-line tool on my Mac and found that I always got at least a couple of dates that were different. (Macs run a lot faster than iOS devices)

Modern iOS devices are multi-core, interrupt driven devices, so the results will vary from run to run.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: Only nitpicking: 15 decimal digits is the *total* precision of a double. For a timestamp of e.g. 565102963.784723 with 9 decimal digits before the decimal point that leaves 6 fractional decimal digits, i.e. microsecond precision.

Comment: Good point. It's significant digits. Interestingly, the code above reports differences of ≈9.5e-07 at the smallest, which would seem to be below the resolution I'd expect.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format it is “15 to 17 significant decimal digits.” – `let t = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate ; print(t.nextUp - t)` prints 1.1920928955078125e-07, that is the difference between two representable numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely each object is different from another object because every individual object has its different address.

Comment: `Date` is a *value,* not an object. Even for `NSDate` (which is an object) the `compare()` method compares the represented points in time, not the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

When You create date by Date() system requested new timestamp. Depending on whole system load You can get small delay. Date objects are sensetive to miliseconds, so You have no guarantee that objects will be created in same milisecond. To check this You can check timeIntervalSince1970 of each date (this method will return Unix timestamp.

Comment: Actually Date objects use a Double to represent their value, so they are sensitive to sub-picosecond differences. (Doubles have ≈15 decimal digits of precision). The real limitation is the resolution on the internal clock.